# Смешивание SDL и WinAPI

Tags: c, windows, sdl

Подскажите, *законно* ли это?

Например, я разрабатываю приложение только под **Windows**, кросс-платформенность мне не нужна. От **SDL** мне требуется только графика, звук и обработка событий ввода. От **WinAPI** я бы хотел использовать **MessageBox()**, **CreateFile()**, сокеты, многопоточность и пр.

Могут ли возникнуть какие-то конфликты?

Comment: `Подскажите, законно ли это?` - слово `законно` надо исключить из лексикона, есть понятие `возможно` и `невозможно` :) По вопросу, можно подумать что SDL использует что то иное чем WinAPI :)

Comment: Значит проблем возникнуть не должно?

Comment: Messagebox'ы есть и в SDL2...

Comment: Там есть и примитивы синхронизации, а так же многопоточность и работа с файлами... Но с этим еще нужно разбираться, поэтому хотелось бы использовать то, с чем я уже достаточно долго работал.

Comment: Мне кажется, проблем не должно быть, особенно если окно создавать через SDL.

Comment: Единственное что случиться, это ваш код не будет кроссплатформенный, при смешивании API.

Comment: @NewView, "законно ли это" - просто отсылка к мемам про плохих парней. Не более. ОП пошутил.